# email validator pattern on JS

Tags: javascript, validation, comments

So I have a form with email field, and I have a validator function for the form, I moved the function to the script of the page of the form and it gets the '@' char as a comment, what can I do about it?

```
 $.validator.addMethod("customEmail",
        function (value) {
            return /^([\w-]+((?:\.[\w-]+)*(?:\+[\w-]+)*)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2})?)$/.test(value);
        },
        contactFormInvalidMailError
    );
```

Comment: Is that a jQuery validate plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regular Expersion: `/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/`
First: name before @ is not limited, so use +. Domains "com", "org" or "net" have length 3, so add {2, 3}. I don’t why @ is comment, my regex works for me.